# In wordpress plugin check if user is admin before running a function

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I check if a user is admin before running a function in a Wordpress plugin. Something that seems like it should be trivial is a pain.

I've looked at dozens of posts online and can't find one thing that works. I tried the following for example (among half a dozen other things) which is a function in a plugin :

```
global $current_user;
if ( $current_user->role[0]=='administrator' ) {    

    function remove_post_metaboxes() {
        remove_meta_box( 'formatdiv','album','normal' );
    }
    add_action('admin_menu','remove_post_metaboxes');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was doing this wrong, the answer supplied by ReLeaf is partially correct but nobody pointed out that instead of trying to wrap the function like the example I gave in the original question and is why i was getting a blank admin screen :

```
global $current_user;
if ( $current_user->role[0]=='administrator' ) {    

    function remove_post_metaboxes() {
        remove_meta_box( 'formatdiv','album','normal' );
    }
    add_action('admin_menu','remove_post_metaboxes');
}
```

I should have had the conditional inside the function instead :

```
function remove_post_metaboxes() {
    global $current_user;
    if ( $current_user->role[0]=='administrator' ) {
        remove_meta_box( 'formatdiv','album','normal' );
    }
}
add_action('admin_menu','remove_post_metaboxes');
```

So that's how it's done, thanks me for pointing it out to me ;)

Comment: A cleaner way to check for the administrator role, especially if there's a possibility an administrator is assigned to other roles (perhaps custom roles) would be: 
`in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles )`

Answer (score 3):

```
 <?php if (current_user_can( 'manage_options' )) {
          // do stuff
  } ?>
```

Comment: I've tried that already but anyway I tried again and it makes my admin area go blank. So doing the following blanks out my wordpress : if (current_user_can( 'manage_options' )) {    
    function remove_post_metaboxes() {
        remove_meta_box( 'formatdiv','album','normal' );
    }
    add_action('admin_menu','remove_post_metaboxes');
}

Comment: even removing all functions from the plugin file and just using nothing but -  if (current_user_can( 'manage_options' )) { }    gives me a white page so it simply does not work, I don't know why it's getting up votes.

Answer (score 2):

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
// print_r($current_user);
if ($current_user->has_cap('administrator')) {

    // do something 
    echo 'is an admin';
}
```

Comment: You are half right, check my accepted answer to see where I was going wrong and nobody noticed. I found your conditional was a better 'looking' way of checking for admin than the way ReLeaf suggested.